# The best way to achieve a nonblocking connection (no multithreaded solutions please)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock

```
#define ID_ERR_NONE 0
#define ID_ERR_CREATESOCKET 1
#define ID_ERR_CONNECT 2


int Connect(SOCKET* s, unsigned __int32 addr, unsigned __int16 port) 
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sai;

    *s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(INVALID_SOCKET != *s) {
        sai.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sai.sin_port = htons(port);
        sai.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = addr;

        if(SOCKET_ERROR != connect(*s, (PSOCKADDR)&sai, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)))
            return ID_ERR_NONE;
        else return ID_ERR_CONNECT;
    } else return ID_ERR_CREATESOCKET;
}
```

Here's my current code, and it works fine as it stands,
but the limitation is, it will cause my main thread to
freeze until it gets connected, so the question I have is
how do I achieve a nonblocking connection successfully.
Not looking for code so much as I am looking for a detailed
 
explanation
The best, most detailed answer will get my vote.

Comment: Have a look at I/O Completion ports: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you want non-blocking behavior your `Connect` function will also have to behave this way. Create the socket, set it to non-blocking, then return the socket handle. Your calling function is then free to call `select` to wait for data with a specific timeout.

Comment: Reading here might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Proposal by @CaptainObvlious is the best approach (since it is the only possible one to achieve what you want). Though of course "best" is not necessarily "good", since the code becomes quite a bit more complex. I would still use a worker thread with a blocking connect (yes, I've read that you don't want that, but it's _simple_). Generally, async I/O with threads that block is a lot simpler than anything else.

Comment: @Damon Nice, thank you! I'm going to see if I can implement CaptainObvlious's suggestion, but I'll leave the question open, incase someone wants to leave a nice lengthy answer.

Comment: Is it a console application?

Comment: Problem with async (nonblocking or overlapped) I/O is that it's somewhat unintuitive and unreliable. The function call must **fail** to work as intended (and then you select/wait on completion or for readiness later), but sometimes, the async operation *succeeds*, which means it completes "immediately". Though especially under Windows "immediately" can be a quite liberal wording, meaning _milliseconds_. Using a thread that blocks is simple. When the operation is done, the thread unblocks. No ifs and whens attached, no special cases and obscure behavior.